# How do I return the value of a specific cell within a range on Google Sheets based on current date?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula

I have a spreadsheet that I'm using to track weekly performance metrics and want to create a summary page that only shows me the value of each metric for the current week.

The worksheet is currently set up with dates across the top in the first row and metric names down the side in column B.

[image: Screenshot of current spreadsheet layout]

My summary page is set up with metric names in column A and current value in column B.

[image: Screenshot of summary page]

I'm looking for a formula that will insert the present value of each metric based on the current date into the summary page. The dates in row 1 indicate the last date of the reporting period (Saturdays).

The name of the sheet where the data is being pulled from is "KPIs" and the full range of the data is C2:BB80 (C1:BB1 is the dates and A and B are metric categories and names)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Please [edit](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/170674/edit) your question and insert a [table](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tables) of sample data together with another table that shows your _manually entered_ desired results. Also consider sharing a publicly editable sample spreadsheet. There is a [blank sheet maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) that lets you share safely.

Answer (score 0):

Use `filter()` and `weeknum()`, like this:

```
=filter(KPIs!C2:BB, weeknum(KPIs!C1:BB1) = weeknum(today()))
```

To get KPI names as well, use an [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), like this:

```
={ KPIs!B2:B, filter(KPIs!C2:BB, weeknum(KPIs!C1:BB1) = weeknum(today())) }
```

See [filter()](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093197) and [weeknum()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3294949).